# Configuration which one should I be using? From fluent tutorial or from cookbook 3.0?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-2, fluent-nhibernate, repository-pattern, ninject

I am reading nhibernate cookbook 3.0 and the fluent tutorial and I am kinda confused which one I should be using(cookbook by itself has many different ways)

Fluent Nhibernate tutorial

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
  return Fluently.Configure()
    .Database(
      SQLiteConfiguration.Standard
        .UsingFile("firstProject.db")
    )
    .Mappings(m =>
      m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
    .ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema)
    .BuildSessionFactory();
}

private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
  // delete the existing db on each run
  if (File.Exists(DbFile))
    File.Delete(DbFile);

  // this NHibernate tool takes a configuration (with mapping info in)
  // and exports a database schema from it
  new SchemaExport(config)
    .Create(false, true);
}
```

cookbook 3.0 pg(76) web request

```
1.  In the hibernate-configuration section of web.config, add the current_
session_context_class property with a value of web.

2.  If it doesn't exist already, add a new Global application class (Global.asax).

3.  In Global.asax, add these using statements.

using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Context;

4.  Create a static property named SessionFactory.

public static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; 
private set; }

5.  In the Application_Start method, add the following code.

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
  var nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
  SessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
}
6.  In the Application_BeginRequest method, add the following code.
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession();
  CurrentSessionContext.Bind(session);
}

7.  In the Application_EndRequest method, add the following code:
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  var session = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(SessionFactory);
  session.Dispose();
}
```

Then they just use this to run it.

```
Guid productId = new Guid(Request["id"]);
Eg.Core.Product product;
var session = Global.SessionFactory.GetCurrentSession();
using (var tran = session.BeginTransaction())
{
  product = session.Get<Eg.Core.Product>(productId);
  tran.Commit();
}
Page.Title = product.Name;
Label1.Text = product.Name;
Label2.Text = product.Description;
```

With the fluent tutorial I am also kinda confused where I would typically put that code in an asp.net mvc application. I am trying to use the repository pattern with ninject(DI injection).

So with both ways I am not sure how to make it work with ninject and the repository pattern.

Is either way better for the repository pattern and Di?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try to download the whole solution to run the project? These are just samples of code and you need the whole setup: VS project with Entity classes, mappings, repositories etc.

I would go to http://www.sharparchitecture.net/ and https://github.com/sharparchitecture download their Northwind sample project that has the exact setup that you need. You will have to find the Northwind database and install it on you local machine then modify the NHibernate.config to point to your database.

Comment: I downloaded the the source code of the book but their seems to be no solution file with them.